# setTimeout into JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I transfer JSON object like this with PHP to JavaScript

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$json['js'] = "setTimer('func()');";
echo json_encode($json);
```

And in JavaScript:

```
function setTimer(func) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        eval(func);
    }, 2000);
}
```

The problem doesn't work the first time always. It works after the second call.
What is the good solution for `setTimeout` ?

Edit: with header x-www-urlencode its work...

Comment: JSON is usually used to represent data - it's not really the place to put executable code.  This sounds a bit like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Ah ok because i use ajax and if i want to execute setTimeout what is the good solution ? (sry for my little english)

Comment: some insight on the problem you are trying to solve would really help

Comment: The problem in my code with `application/json` not work first time (i need to reclick for work) but with `x-www-urlencode` and `JSON.parse` its work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to `get` a JSON object from a PHP page through ajax, it's better not to rely on setTimeout. Instead, use the server to `echo` a JSON, retrieve it client side and use for whatever you need.

```
// server.php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo "{\"a\": 1}";
```

And, on client side,

```
// client.html
<script>
   // avoid the use of eval, it's evil. Pass a function as a parameter.
   function setTimer(func) {
      setTimeout(function() {return func()}, 2000)
   }
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open('GET', 'server.php', true);
   request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){ 
         var response = this.response;
         // do what you intended.
         setTimer(function() { console.log(response) })
      }
   }
</script>
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest